# can't drag item after scrolling to the end of dialog - react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I got an issue with ***react-dnd*** library when I did a drag & drop from a dialog

When I drag the item without scrolling to the end of the dialog every thing works fine ,

But when I scroll to the end of dialog the item can't be dragged

Also another thing strange that the problem doesn't exist in Firefox browser , only in chrome

Note : 
I did put a console.log in **beginDrag** and **endDrag** I found that endDrag is called directly after begin

ScreenShot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YX2Uxn66luARilVfJXucJgjBzhoaMAkU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

Sometimes the manipulation of dom for custom drag layer doesn't work ( in chrome ) after the drag start

like this one :

```
<div ref={this.badItemRef} className="badItem" style={{
                opacity: isDragging ? "0" : "1",
                 height: isDragging ? 0 : '',
            }}>
</div>
```

I fixed that by manipulating the css of item in **beginDrag** function and wrapped the manipulation by a setTimeOut function

like this :

```
// hide after a timeout
        setTimeout(() => {
            currentItemRef.style.display = "none";
        }, 0)
```

And now every thing looks good !